# MegaCli won't rebuild when set to hotspare

Tags: dell-poweredge, hotswap, megacli

I recently inserted a new drive and marked it as Good. When I then set it to be a Hot Spare, it refuses to rebuild.

```
[root]# MegaCli -PDList -aALL| grep Firm
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Firmware state: Unconfigured(bad)
Firmware state: Hotspare, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
```

After I set it, it just remains a Hot Spare and never rebuilds.

```
[root]# MegaCli -PDHSP -Set -PhysDrv \[32:2\] -aALL

Adapter: 0: Set Physical Drive at EnclId-32 SlotId-2 as Hot Spare Success.

Exit Code: 0x00
[root]# MegaCli -PDList -aALL| grep Firm
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Firmware state: Hotspare, Spun Up
Firmware state: Unconfigured(bad)
Firmware state: Hotspare, Spun Up
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
```

What did I do wrong? For the record, the Unconfigured(bad) is 32:4 and it is a bad drive that failed. Nothing that was already marked as Hot Spare kicked in and I confirmed the auto setting to go from Hotspare to Online was set.

```
[root]# MegaCli -pdrbld -showprog -physdrv\[32:2\] -aALL

Device(Encl-32 Slot-2) is not in rebuild process
```

This is a Dell R710 PowerEdge server.

Comment: Are all disks SAS?

Comment: Your question appears to show the issue. Its a mix of SATA and SAS drives. Any way to allow them to mix and match?  PD Type: SATA
PD Type: SATA
PD Type: SAS
PD Type: SATA
PD Type: SAS
PD Type: SATA

Comment: Maybe raid firmware update will help you, but chance is small. You can create new logical drive on sata disks and join it with old logical drive by LVM or by another same software service.

Comment: Mikhail:  Thank you. I will work to just swap out the SAS with SATA drives and that should solve my issue. Thanks for bringing this discrepancy to my attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Mikhail's comments, the issue is SAS vs SATA.

In short, SAS & SATA drives in a RAID are incompatible without jumping through hoops and crossing fingers. As such, it's easier to just make all the drives SATA on my Dell R710 Poweredge vs. some custom hack to allow for a mix of SAS/SATA.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I'm not sure there is much more detail to offer. In short, SAS & SATA drives in a Raid are incompatible without jumping through hoops and crossing fingers. As such, it's easier to just make all the drives SATA on my Dell R710 Poweredge vs. some custom hack to allow for a mix of SAS/SATA.